# Fast edit existed sharepoint list with Access or something

Tags: custom-list

I have some custom lists in Sharepoint2013, with a lot of data (~8000 record/each list). I must edit some of it, however, edit some 8000_row_data_table in Excel is easy, but in sharepoint web, it's nighmare.
**Is there any way to fast edit it?**
I did google the "edit sharepoint list in excel" and "edit sharepoint list in access" but got no helpful result.
Do you have face same problem with me? Is there any solution for it?

Comment: You're trying to update the data in the list?

Comment: @jpollar : yes, I need to update list data.

Answer (score 1):

You can link your SharePoint list to an Access database and create SQL to update the data.

See here: [Connect your Access 2013 Web Apps to SharePoint Lists](https://blogs.office.com/2012/08/30/connect-your-access-2013-web-apps-to-sharepoint-lists/)